# Как вставить в ключ массива из переменной в PHP?

Tags: php

Пробую по разному:

```
$var["{$dir}"];
$var[$dir];
$var[(string)$dir];
...
```

Как только не пробую, постоянно выдает ошибку: `Notice: Undefined index: значение in ...`

А если вывести саму переменную `$dir`, то значение выводится. Фантастика!

[image: Не могу получить значение]

Comment: Второй вариант. а ошибку выдает потому что такого элемента в **массиве** нет

Comment: @Ипатьев Есть!
`Array
(
    [kylticket] => 2.2
)`

Comment: нету. первый навык программиста - **научиться верить своим глазам.** и если пхп говорит что нету такого элемента - значит его НЕТ

Comment: В какой ключ-то вставить?

Comment: Правильно будет `$var['kylticket'] = $dir;`

Comment: поэтому надо протереть глаза и проверить, что у тебя в $dir. обычно у нубов там первод строки.

Comment: @vp_arth думаю суть в том, что ты получаешь заранее не известное значение, заносишь его в переменную, а потом вызываешь как ключ

Comment: @Oleksandr, но у него очевидно `$dir == 'значение'`

Comment: Нету ни пробелов, ни отступов. Я сперва вывожу значение `$dir` и получаю его спокойно, а потом пытаюсь в массиве `$var` найти значение 2.2 по ключу из переменной, и все никак.

Comment: Приведите весь код, включая то, откуда вы взяли `$dir`

Comment: Еще раз. "Я сперва вывожу" означает что ты выводишь неизвестно что неизвестно куда. Как ты узнал, что "Нету ни пробелов, ни отступов"? А браузер, в который ты, как все ламеры, выводишь свое значение, отображает отступы? Хотя бы в исходник HTML догадайся заглянуть

Comment: @Ипатьев я обрезал перед использованием с помощью str_replace в массиве задал все возможные отступы и пробелы \r\n PHP_EOL и т.д.

Comment: Это еще одна ошибка начинающих программистов. "Я сделал то-то и то-то" - это вообще ни о чем. Ты можешь воображать что угодно, но реальность тебе говорит человеческим голосом совсем противоположное. Надо не блеять "я обрезал" а ПРОВЕРЯТЬ, ЧТО НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ ЛЕЖИТ В ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ. `echo rawurlencode($dir."<br>".key($updates_result));`

Comment: Сделай дамп `var_dump(array_keys($updates_result));` а потом руками ключи подставь

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо, проблема решена, в переменной подключался <script>, поэтому даже обрезка пробелов не помогла. Но зачем так нервничать? Я и не говорил, что я профи. И о функции `rawurlencode` не знал. Спасибо, что толкнули носом.

Comment: Ну тут просто важен в первую очередь здравый смысл. Если система говорит что ключа нет - значит так оно и есть, и надо не отнекиваться, а искать причину. <script> мог показать и просто просмотр **исходного текста HTML** в браузере

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу помощь, вопросы исчерпаны...

Answer (score 0):

Как вставить в ключ массива из переменной в PHP?

Как я понял то вам необходимо получить новый массив с известными вам ключами.
Если я не правильно понял, то уточните вопрос и я перепишу ответ, а если правильно то вот решение:

Данными действиями

```
$var["{$dir}"];
$var[$dir];
$var[(string)$dir];
```

вы вызываете элемент данного массива по ключу $dir
если вы хотите занести в массив $var новый ключ, то укажите ему любое приемлемое для вас значение по этому ключу как здесь например:

```
//$var["{$dir}"]='';
$var[$dir]='';//операция присвоения - мы присваиваем массиву  $var 
              //значение(пустое в данном случае - пустой символ) по ключу $dir
//$var[(string)$dir]='';
print_r($var);
```